# How to set cmake command for required package

Tags: cmake

The part of code in **cmakelist.txt** file of project:

```
# find the required packages
find_package(GLM REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "GLM included at ${GLM_INCLUDE_DIR}")
find_package(GLFW3 REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Found GLFW3 in ${GLFW3_INCLUDE_DIR}")
find_package(ASSIMP REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Found ASSIMP in ${ASSIMP_INCLUDE_DIR}")
# find_package(SOIL REQUIRED)
# message(STATUS "Found SOIL in ${SOIL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
# find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
# message(STATUS "Found GLEW in ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

How to set arguments in cmake command? like this:

```
cmake -Dxxx=PATH_TO_REQUIRED_PACKAGE_DIR -G xcode
```

I tried to run

```
cmake -DGLFW3_DIR=/Users/aaronlee/workspaces/cpp/LearnOpenGL-master/glfw-3.3.8 -G xcode
```

It still showed error:Could NOT find GLFW3 (missing: GLFW3_LIBRARY)

Comment: If CMake can't find the package, it's not installed on your system. Or you have a typo...

Comment: Try it without the version number in find_package

Comment: "How to set arguments in cmake command?" - The arguments are passed with `-D` key. You passed them correctly. If you wonder whether the arguments you pass **actually affects** on `find_package(GLFW3)`, then consult script `FindGLFW.cmake` which is shipped with your project (probably, [that one](https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL/blob/master/cmake/modules/FindGLFW3.cmake)). Hint: Missing **only** `XXX_LIBRARY` variable usually signals that installation has been **found**, but it doesn't contain libraries suitable for the platform, against which you are building the project.

Comment: BTW, what is **content** of the directory `/Users/aaronlee/workspaces/cpp/LearnOpenGL-master/glfw-3.3.8`? If it resembles [that source code](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/tree/3.3.8), then it cannot be used by `find_package`: you need to have GLFW **installed**, not its *source* files.

Answer (score 0):

I've learned to like cmake over time, but unfortunately a question like "how to find required packages" never has a simple answer in cmake. You'll have to bite the bullet and learn more about how it works.

With [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html), there are two basic alternatives routes to finding a package:

1. Config Mode: cmake looks for a package config file (`<packagename>Config.cmake` or similar), which contains all required information about the package. This usually applies to finding other cmake packages that were properly installed. CMake will search lots of default locations for this config file. To point it to a specific location, you can specify `-D<packagename>_DIR=<path-to-directory-containing-package-config-file>`.
2. Module Mode: cmake looks for a find script that it will use to find the package. This usually applies to finding system libraries or other non-cmake libraries, where you have to search the system for certain files. Some libraries, like openssl, provide find scripts by default. Others may not, meaning you'll have to write your own or look online. If you do have a find script, you can set `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` to the directory containing the script, so cmake will find it. Once the script is running you can guide it, if needed, by specifying `-D<packagename>_ROOT=<path-to-sysroot-containing-headers-and-lib>`.

To help you more specifically we would need to know whether the packages you require are installed into the system or you just have their source code checked out somewhere. Also, the exact error message cmake shows you would be helpful - it usually says right there whether setting xyz_DIR or xyz_ROOT would be helpful.